# Por que no funciona este método extensión?

Tags: c#, método

Método extensión:

```
namespace PantallaHornosApp
{
 public static class ExceptionHelper
 {
    public static string GetErrorDetails(this Exception ex)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("Error: {0}", ex.InnerException);
        Exception innerExc = ex.InnerException;
        int level = 1;
        while (innerExc != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(innerExc.Message))
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Inner Exception {0}: {1}", new[] { level.ToString(), innerExc.Message });
            }
            innerExc = innerExc.InnerException;
            level++;
        }
        sb.AppendFormat("Stack trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
        sb.AppendFormat("Target site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
        sb.AppendFormat("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
 }
}
```

Lo quiero llamar asi:

```
namespace PantallaHornosApp
{
 public class PartesController : ApiController
 {

    public IHttpActionResult Post(Parte parte)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HornosContext db = new HornosContext())
            {
                db.Partes.Add(parte);
                int res = db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ERROR
            //Error 1   'System.Exception' does not contain a definition for 'GetErrorDetails' and no extension method 'GetErrorDetails' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\atorres\proyectos\pantallashornos\pantallahornosapp\api\partescontroller.cs    51  37  PantallaHornosApp

            Trace.TraceError(ex.GetErrorDetails());
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

- Intellisence no me lo identifica.
- Estan en el mismo namespace
- La clase y el método extensión son estáticos
- Estoy usando la palabra "this"
- Todo esta en el mismo proyecto
- Ya reinicié visual studio
- Ya quité y volví a agregar el proyecto en la solución
- Ya le di clean - rebuild

El problema tiene que ver con el espacio de nombres y no con el tipo Exception, hice un método extensión para String y tampoco lo encuentra

Que esta pasando?

Comment: ¿La clase estática está en el mismo proyecto de VS o aparte?

Comment: Todo esta en el mismo proyecto

Comment: intentaste compilando el proyecto? puede que si hay algun otro fallo no reconozca la extension. Tambien prueba realizando un Rebuild de la solucion

Comment: Ya le di clean - rebuild a la solucion

Comment: que pasa si tomas ese codigo y lo defines justo debajo del controller ? no lleves la definicion del namespace solo la definicion de la class static de la extension

Comment: Ok, lo voy a intentar

Comment: Por cierto, no ayuda a la solución pero tienes un bug. Si inicialmente la `ex.InnerException == null` tu código se cae en los `AppendFormat` por `NullReferenceException` porque `innerExc` es null

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Tienes razon, en esas lineas no era innerExc, era solo ex, gracias por notarlo

Comment: Ya funciono, publico respuesta en un momento

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz De hecho hasta le falta una linea `innerExc = innerExc.InnerException;` Gracias una vez mas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Deshabilité Web Essentials 2013.5
2. Reinicié VS , igual no funcionó, pero no se si deshabilitar Web Essentials  ayudó en algo
3. Copié el codigo del metodo extensión y lo pegué en un archivo nuevo, borré el original
4. Reinicié VS y funcionó

Extra: Volví a habilitar Web Essentials y el problema no se repitió.

Answer (score 1):

Pon el using correspondiente en la clase donde lo deseas invocar.

```
using PantallaHornosApp;
```

En las ayudas (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/bb383977.aspx) dice lo siguiente:

> Los métodos de extensión únicamente se encuentran dentro del ámbito cuando el espacio de nombres se importa explícitamente en el código fuente con una directiva using.

Comment: Gracias, si lo tenia puesto, ya quedo resuelto (ver mi respuesta)